# How to use Spyder to set breakpoints on a command-line-based script that requires arguments?

Tags: python, spyder

I recovered a project where the code is originally launched in a command line with passed arguments.

To debug it using Spyder, I created a basic python file to call the python program using

```
subprocess.popen(['python', 'FileName', 'arguments'])
```

(I also tried `os.system()` with the same behavior).

As often, I'm using breakpoints to find code errors but it seems not to be working inside a subprocess and the program doesn't stop (not at all) as expected, and I'm wondering why; I'm probably missing something.

So:

- I'm using subprocess, but is there another more relevant way to run python programs with passed arguments
- How can I debug the code: is there an option inside Spyder (looked for, but didn't see obvious things)

Comment: I edited to remove mention of subprocess in the title (but left it in the body), because that's not what your _actual_ issue is. Your actual issue is how to pass arguments and setting breakpoints when debugging with Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder (or any other Python debugger) is only able to debug the current program. As soon as you use `subprocess` or `os.system` you launch a new unrelated program, and Spyder cannot debug it.

The correct way it to directly load the other (main) Python file, the one that you try to launch through `popen(['python', 'FileName'...`, in Spyder, and then set the arguments in the Run / Configuration per file... (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
<kbd>F6</kbd>) menu. Search for the *General Settings* group and then you will be able to give the command line arguments.

Once this is done, you can debug your program normally....